# Capacitor Array calculation to simulate high-voltage Regen in Electric Vehicle

Tags: capacitor, high-voltage, supercapacitor, electric-machine

Good morning group, I was asked something of a puzzle: We currently have an experimental EV car powered by a large nickel-salt battery. With the ignition on and foot off the 'gas', the battery shows 370 volts, with a small draw of 1 amp. While driving, I've seen up to 100 amps delivered to the motor.

I've been asked to simulate a 'regen' system so we can test our Inverter. I need to supply 30 amps of energy back to the battery for a duration of 30 seconds. I have seen high voltage caps out there (and am very much aware of how dangerous this level of energy is), however I'm stumped on calculating exactly which capacitor size I am looking for, or how I would calculate resistance to assure a 30 second delivery time.

Comment: Energy isn't dangerous only the rate of exchange of energy. Your requirements are unclear - why do you talk of high voltage capacitors? If you want to dump energy back to the battery (in order to presumably charge it) then say that (if that is what you want which is unclear to me). "30 amps of energy" has nothing to do with energy - amps are amps; joules are joules.

Comment: Andy, that's correct, I want to dump energy back into the battery to recharge it, at 30 amps for 30 seconds. Apologies for being unclear.

Comment: What voltage is generated? AC or DC? If AC, what frequency (range)? How efficient does your system need to be to be minimally acceptable? What does the battery voltage rise to when fed back 30 amps? Is this 30 amp to be a constant feed i.e. does the battery need a constant charge current or is 30 amps a maximum permitted value?

Comment: With further clarification from my co-worker, it looks like we don't have to go 'back' through the inverter, therefore we can keep things all DC. We need to dump energy back into the battery, at the rate of 30 amps for 30 seconds. Since the battery is 370V, I assume we have to supply the same voltage back.

Comment: Capacitors are not appropriate for this. Just get a suitable (30 A @ 400 V = 12 kW!) AC-input power supply.

Comment: I agree, Dave. For whatever reason, the owner wants to demonstrate the battery's ability to be charged while driving, and we don't have a long enough cord!

Comment: I've voted to close this question because you don't appear to understand what I'm asking and therefore you are most likely to be unable to clarify your question. You don't seem to understand what an inverter does or why it does it and why I asked if the motor was AC or DC.

Comment: I don't get it.  If you have a battery, why don't you just use the battery for that.  To be clear are you looking for a way to dump excess energy?  That is easy.

Comment: Forget capacitors. Just use a second battery at a higher state of charge, (it can be a lower capacity one) and suitable circuitry to limit the current to 30A.

Comment: I thought you were just testing the battery. If this is already built into a drivable vehicle, then the motor itself is your power source. I'm getting the impression that neither you nor "the owner" really understand the fundamental issues here. Exactly what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to *dump* excess energy.  I gather you don't want to *actually* regenerate into the battery *yet*, because your tech isn't there yet.  What you need is a **dynamic brake grid** or basically a big fat resistor.

Blindly connecting the resistor in series with the battery won't work. In off-grid solar panel systems that use batteries, the solar charge controller has a pair of terminals called "Dump". Examples of such controllers are Morningstar or Midnight Electric.  When the controller is receiving more energy than the battery can absorb, the controller routes the excess power to these "Dump" terminals, which then powers something like a water heater.  Ideally, your controller has a "dump" terminal that does the same thing.  This is where to connect your dynamic brake grid.

---

Home Depot sells 2000W, 240V Cadet heaters for $50. They are bulletproof and have plenty of surface area, so they will convection cool just fine.

```
 2000W @ 240V = 8.333 amps, repeating of course.
 8.333 amps @ 240V E=IR 240=8.333R.   R=28.8 ohm.
```

Your voltage won't exceed 480V so use them in series pairs*, giving 57.6 ohms.  Say Regen floats battery voltage up to 380V.

```
380V into 57.6 ohms is E=IR 380=57.6I.  I=6.6 amps.
```

Five such pairs should be able to dissipate 33 amps at your expected voltage.  It would be very hokeydokey, and bulky, but will work - and it's hard to argue with the price.

If money is no object, you can do the same thing *much more compactly* with Chromalox style strip heaters, but then you'd need to actively cool them. It would help if you could find a fan happy to run on 380V.

---

* they are not *listed* for series connection, so this would violate NEC 110.3b. However NEC is inapplicable to automobiles.

Answer (score 1):

The battery can not be charged while driving it can only be charged while braking. To simulate that, you would need to shut off the connection from the battery to the inverter and connect it to a charging system. Doing that while the car is coasting or being mechanically braked is not much different from doing it with the car parked.

If you must do it while moving, another battery bank as suggested by @Brian Drummond would probably be the easiest solution.

To do it with a capacitor bank, you would need to have a voltage boost converter that could supply a voltage sufficiently higher than the battery voltage to charge while the input form the capacitor bank drops. If it takes 400 volts to charge, the energy required to supply 30 amps for 30 seconds would be 400 X 30 X 30 = 360,000 joules. Since the capacitor must provide some minimum voltage to the boost converter, it can not discharge to zero, so not all of the stored energy can be recovered. If the boost converter can operate between 100 and 400 volts, the capacitance needed would need to be 2 X 360,000 / (400 - 100)^2 = 8 farads. That is a big capacitor bank.

Comment: An unrealistically large capacitor bank, and costly ...which tells you it's the wrong way to do it.